# Probability of hitting the right answer

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics

We have an algorithm that has 1/512 chance that it will result in right answer.

What is the chance that we will get right answer when we run the algorithm 512 times?

Using the idea we are running it 512 times i came up with

$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{512}\frac{k}{512}}{512}$

which resulted in wrong answer, what is formula to calculate it?

Comment: This is not clear.  I'm guessing that you mean for each trial to be independent, but you don't say that and it is not a very natural assumption...after all, whatever caused it to be off the first time might cause it to be wrong again.

Comment: Also:  what do you mean "get right answer"?  do you mean "get the right answer at least once in those $512$ trials"? or do you mean something else?

Comment: @lulu yes exactl  get the right answer atleast once in those 512 trials

Answer (score 1):

The probability that you get the right answer is difficult to compute directly -- you have to worry about how many times you got the right answer to compute it.

Instead, let's think about this: what's the probability that you DON'T get the right answer on any run?  This is easy to compute: you know the probability for any one of the runs, and all of your runs are independent.

Now, if you have the probability that you never get the right answer, how can you find the probability that you did get the right answer at least once?